# Technically, can all functions be a void function?

Tags: c, function

For example:

```
int f1() {
    return 3;
}
void f2(int *num) {
    *num = 3;
}
int n1, n2;
n1 = f1();
f2(&n2);
```

With f1, we can return a value and do "variable=f1()"
But the same can be done with a void function that updates the value of that variable given its address without having to do "variable=f1()".

So, does this mean that we can actually just use void functions for everything? Or is there something that a void function cannot do to replace another int function/(type) function?

Comment: If you are talking about functions _you_ define, well, more or less yes. Why are you asking ? Technically you can write any program in assembly code but why should one bother?

Comment: AFAIR `main` function needs to return `int` (though as the only function it doesn't need to to it explicitly). Some library functions also returns values. You are not forced to define any function to return, though it would lead to some disaster sooner or later.

Comment: If we consider operators as a special kind of function and then no, they can not be void. E.g. if `operator +` does not return a rvalue, the language is completely unusable.

Comment: You can. You can also, write programs never using the `-` operator, design a CPU with just one instruction and write a whole novel without the letter "e". It's impractical, but it can be done.

Comment: yes but you can't use it in expressions anymore `sin(x)*tan(y)-log(z)*exp(t)`...

Comment: @Art could you actually do a CPU with only 1 instruction? I would think two at a minimum (also, look Ma! no E's!)

Comment: @Dave I seem to recall it was something like "subtract a from b storing the result in c and branch to x if result is negative". Pretty sure there are more possibilities, that one I recall being the easiest to understand.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc actually, he can. There is a way to use a function that returns void in an expression. `sin(x) * tan(y) - (f2(&n), n)`

Comment: @user3528438 what is `operator+`? The question is tagged `C`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz you can call it `+ operator` if you want to.

Comment: @Michael Walz `operator +` is specified in C11 §6.5.3.3 2 Unary arithmetic operators

Comment: @chux OK, I thought he was talking about the C++ `operator+`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem with making everything a void function (which in some people's lexicon is called a "routine") is that you can't chain them easily:

```
f(g(x))
```

becomes, if you really want to chain it:

```
int gout;
f((g(x, &gout), gout))
```

Which is painful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could use `void` return types for everything and rely exclusively on returning via modified parameters. In fact, you could avoid using functions entirely and put everything in your `main` method.

As with any other feature of the language, return values give you particular advantages, and its up to you to decide if you want them. Here are some advantages of return values off the top of my head:

- Returned values can be assigned to `const` variables, which can make your code easier to reason about
- Certain types of optimisation can be applied by the compiler for returned values (this is more applicable to C++ RVO but may also apply to C's structs; I'm not sure)
- Code which uses returned values is often easier to read, especially when the functions are mathematical (e.g. imagine having to declare all the temporaries manually for a large mathematical operation using sin/cos/etc. if they required the output to be via parameters). Compare:

  ```
  double x = A*sin(a) + B*cos(b);
  ```

  with

  ```
  double tmpA, tmpB;
  sin(&tmpA, a);
  cos(&tmpB, b);
  double x = A * tmpA + B * tmpB;
  ```

  or to use a similar structure as John Zwinck suggested in his answer:

  ```
  double tmpA, tmpB;
  double x = A * (sin(&tmpA, a), tmpA) + B * (cos(&tmpB, b), tmpB);
  ```
- It is guaranteed that the value will be set no matter what happens inside the function, as this is enforced by the compiler (except some very special cases such as longjumps)
- You do not need to worry about checking if the assigned value is used or not; you can return the value and if the requester doesn't need it, they can ignore it (compare this to needing NULL-checks everywhere in your alternative method)

Of course there are also disadvantages:

- You only get a single return value, so if your function logically returns multiple types of data (and they can't logically be combined into a single struct), returning via parameters may be better
- Large objects may introduce performance penalties due to the need to copy them (which is why RVO was introduced in C++, which makes this much less of an issue)

Answer (score 2):

> So, does this mean that we can actually just use void functions for everything?

Indeed. And as it turn out, doing so is a fairly common coding style. But rather than `void`, such styles usually state that the return value should always be reserved for error codes.

In practice, you usually won't be able to stick to such a style consistently. There are a some special cases where not using the return value becomes inconvenient.

For example when writing callback functions of the kind used by standard C generic functions `bsearch` or `qsort`. The expect a callback of the format

```
int compare (const void *p1, const void *p2);
```

where the function returns less than zero, more than zero or zero. Design-wise it is important to keep the parameters passed as read-only, you wouldn't want your generic search algorithm to suddenly start modifying the searched contents. So while there is no reason in theory why these kind of functions couldn't be of `void` return type too, in practice it would make the code uglier and harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could; but that does not make it a good idea.

It may not always be convenient or lead to easy to comprehended code.  A function returning void cannot be used directly as an operand in an expression.  For example while you could write:

```
if( f1() == 3 )
{
    ...
}
```

for `f2()` you would have to write:

```
f2( &answer ) ;
if( answer )
{
    ...
}
```

Another issue is one of access control - by passing a pointer to the function you are giving that function indirect access to the caller's data, which is fine so long as the function is well behaved and does not overrun.  A pointer may refer to a single object or an array of objects - the function taking that pointer has to impose appropriate rules, so it is intrinsically less safe.

Comment: Regarding using a voud function in an expression @LuizEduardo's has suggested a method, but that is covered by my  point about "easy to comprehended code".  It is valid but perhaps perverse.